# User manage Service Account to deploy CloudRun instance

Tags: google-cloud-run, service-accounts, google-iam

I need your help please. I am not able to find out what I am missing. I created user managed SA and provided roles

```
roles/run.admin 
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

[image]

but somehow I am not able to see it when creating service:

[image]

I also added impersonation to default compute SA.

[image]

I am pushing changes via terraform:

```
resource "google_service_account" "sa-deployer" {
  project      = local.project_id
  account_id   = "${local.env}-sa-deployer-tf"
  display_name = "Service Account to deploy CloudRun instance"
}

resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "gce-default-account-iam" {
  service_account_id = data.google_compute_default_service_account.default.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
  member             = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa-deployer.email}"

  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.sa-deployer
  ]
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "sa-deployer-run-admin" {
  project = local.project_id
  role    = "roles/run.admin"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa-deployer.email}",
  ]

  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.sa-deployer
  ]
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "sa-deployer-build-admin" {
  project = local.project_id
  role    = "roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa-deployer.email}",
  ]

  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.sa-deployer
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do you deploy your Cloud Run service?

Comment: I am doing manually for now but once it works I will wrap via CloudBuild.

Comment: What are the permissions of the current user, logged on the console?

Comment: I have `Cloud Run Admin` access assigned.

Comment: I think YOU must be serviceAccountUser to be able to list the service account on the project.

Comment: Damn.... you are right!  Kudos @guillaumeblaquiere!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current user must be serviceAccountUser to be able to list the service account on the project.

Answer (score 1):

To allow a user to manage service accounts, grant one of the following roles:

Service Account User (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser): Includes permissions to list service accounts, get details about a service account, and impersonate a service account.

Service Account Admin (roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin): Includes permissions to list service accounts and get details about a service account. Also includes permissions to create, update, and delete service accounts, and to view or change the IAM policy on a service account.

To learn more about these roles, see [Service Accounts roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-accounts-roles).

IAM basic roles(roles/viewer, roles/editor) also contain permissions to manage service accounts. You should not grant basic roles in a production environment, but you can grant them in a development or test environment.

For more information refer to the following documentations.

1. [Permissions to manage service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#permissions).
2. [Listing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#listing).

Comment: That is awesome details. Thank you @Chandra Kiran